# Get NSDate formatted to current device date, time and timezone

Tags: ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I've been looking all over the web but the only things people had were setups where they would have a date formatter and formate the [NSDate date] to a string and that would work just fine. What I need however is that formatted date to be an NSDate. 
I've tried formatting to the string (which works fine) and then back to the NSDate but it never comes out with the right timezone - is just has +0000 with the correct current time for the +0000 timezone.

Is the problem that NSDate always has +0000 timezone and you can't change this? Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: NSDate is not "formatted".  The version you see when you use NSLog on an NSDate is a *diagnostic* representation, and is not guaranteed to remain consistent from one minor iOS version to the next.  You *must* use NSDateFormatter or some other mechanism to convert the NSDate into user-presentable form.

Comment: The reason I'm doing this is because I need the users current NSDate so that I can compare it (NSDate has a compare function) so see if one follows the other.... I guess I could just convert it to text and extract the day out of it and then make it an int and compare ints...?

Comment: An NSDate is, internally, a time in seconds (with fractions) since the "reference date" (Jan 1, 2001 at 12 midnight UTC).  You can get two NSDate values and easily compare them, so long as both were properly encode (so that they represent UTC values).

Comment: (It is unfortunately true that, probably for "compatibility" reasons", the NSDate `description` method prints out a timezone value.  That value is somehow encoded in "spare" bits in the object but is not settable outside of internal iOS function.  The value is meaningless and confusing and should be eliminated.)

Comment: yeah... I ended up just using the formatted string and taking the day number (with some constraints on months and stuff) to accomplish what I needed. The problem with using UTC NSDate is that it could say that the next day is tomorrow and different times depending on the user's timezone and I couldn't have that

Comment: Yes, that is a problem.  Dates are deceptively tricky.  If you want to know if time A is before or after time B then NSDate compares work well.  If you want to know if time A represents yesterday, today, or tomorrow it gets much more complicated.